# Unable to use isoWeekDay with a moment variable

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I am using

```
   getDay(startDate:Moment){   
  var dayOfWeek= startDate.isoWeekday();
 }
```

When I run this in the browser , I get " TypeError: startDate.isoWeekDay is not a function".

I have written unit test to test the value and it works properly. It is only when I am running it in the browser that it is failing. What am I missing?

Comment: How are you calling `getDay`?

Answer (score 1):

It should be moment(startDate).isoWeekday()

Comment: If `startDate` is a Moment object already, you do not need to call `moment()` on it again.